Dovecot Plugin File Missing
Hello I'm using Dovecot and my users and everything is working fine just today I wanted to check the per-user storage limit, and I tried to run this command (dovecot quota get -A) and the answer was (Fatal: Unknown command 'quota', but plugin quota exists. Try to set mail_plugins=quota)
But I checked/etc/dovecot/conf.d, and everywhere, there is no plugin file from which I can change the settings.
Kindly help me in this matter. I will be grateful to you guys

Have you check in /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/ where are the plugins of dovecot?
